# We have observed that user1 can get access of USER2 just by changing the session Id

Tags: javascript, java, security, tomcat, session-cookies

i am facing one issue like if i copy session_id from user1  and use same session-id in USER2

then my session is hijacking from user1 to user2,
I am using Java, tomcat, hibernate , javascript, rest API

any idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: That's how sessions work. Unless the session is invalidated, its id is what ties clients and server together. If your users shared they usernames and passwords would you consider that a security breach or how logins work?

Comment: Unless you want to make your users' life harder. Then you can check the IP address, fingerprint the browser and decide that the user using the session id is not the same that got it in the first place.

Comment: Well a session is the unique connection from client to server, are you saying somebody is copying session id's from one browser to the other?.  If so not much you can do about it,.  I would say you tell your users to stay secure, make sure they log out etc,   maybe use `SessionStorage` instead of of Cookies, these disappear on browser close.   Only option after that is try and make things more tricky to re-use a session on another machine, like check the `user-agent` string, and make sure it's the same one, maybe use IP's as a check, but be aware one user via proxy's could use multiple  IP's.

Comment: What I do to make sessions more secure, I re-validate the tokens every so often, the more often you renew, the more secure.   Another option is using websockets, and attach security to the websocket.   Of course if the user loses connection, they will need to re-login, but it's a very secure way for uses to connect, and lost connections these day's isn't a problem like it used to be.  Eg, I have websockets connected for days without issues.

Comment: @Keith depending on the use case, lost connection is still a thing on mobile for example.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  Yes, I understand that.  eg, Mobile phones go to sleep, and when you re-awake the mobile the connection will be gone.  But like I said you would just need to re-login.   But if security is very important, it's a really nice solution.   I personally use a mix  SessionStorage with token renewal & websocket's.  This seems a good mix of convenience and security.

Comment: @Keith sure, I wasn't contradicting that. Just the claim that lost connections are not an issue. Also, consider someone using your app from a train that goes through a lot of tunnels. *They* will hate you :) As I said, "depending on the use case".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  No problem, didn't think you was contradicting me..  And yes, mobile disconnect, I was just pointing out the sleep one, as that might be something some people don't think off.   Ps, I solve the disconnect issues by making the client app request token renewal, this way disconnects are handled.  I just then use a long expiry on the server end for the token.  This way, users don't have to constantly login on disconnects.  Of course all of this is not 100% secure if somebody has access to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

That's how sessions work. Unless the session is invalidated, its id is what ties clients and server together. If your users shared they usernames and passwords would you consider that a security breach or how logins work?

Unless you want to make your users' life harder. Then you can check the IP address, but then laptop users roaming through wireless connections, or users behind a proxy, will be kicked out of their session as soon as their ip changes.

Or you could fingerprint the browser and decide that the user using the session id is not the same that got it in the first place.

No method will be perfect and all of them will have have trade offs.